# Webpack: Bundle.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules

Here's my **webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./main.js'],
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"},
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        React: 'react',
    },
    target: "node",
};
```

And **Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import Chart from 'chartjs';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import vis from 'vis';
import babel from 'babel-core';
```

The **Bundle.js** is inserted in my Index.html. The browser then gives the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.measureMethods (bundle.js:1297)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:530)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:288)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:158)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:110)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:90)
```

What should I change in the webpack.config.js to make this error go away?

Comment: for my typescript project I added .d.ts file with such content: "declare var process: any;"

Comment: Can you explain how you'd implement that here? In the webpack config..?

Comment: not in the webpack config. in any top-level file and defined as global. it processed by transpiled and declared as global. and now "process" can be used on front. with DefinePlugin from below

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add a plugin to define your env (in webpack config):

```
   plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
```

Comment: Where would you add this to the above config? Setting it below the "target" gives me "Unresolved type DefinePlugin",.

Comment: add "var webpack = require('webpack');" at the top of your webpack.config.js file

Comment: I don't get the error now. Thanks. Testing to see if this solved the overall issue :)

Comment: I don't get the above error anymore. But now instead, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined` .... Any hints on this one? Appreciate it. Opened it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359987/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined

Comment: Im not sure but i see you found a solution :)

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been looking this up for so long now Q.Q.

Comment: For me, this was resolved when I  updated graphql to 14.0.2 from 0.13.2

Answer (score 148):

For Webpack 5, you can reference `process/browser` from the appropriate `plugins` part of `webpack.config.js`:

```js
// webpack needs to be explicitly required
const webpack = require('webpack')
// import webpack from 'webpack' // (if you're using ESM)

module.exports = {

/* ... rest of the config here ... */

  plugins: [
    // fix "process is not defined" error:
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
  ]
}
```

Then run

```
npm install process
```

before building.

Comment: This gives me the error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process/browser' in '/path/to/my/js'`

Comment: you need to "npm install process"- I will update my answer

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I was able to get it working using a slightly different method.  I'll provide my own answer.

Comment: I installed NPM and am getting: ```ERROR in ./node_modules/async/dist/async.mjs 60:25-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process/browser' in 'REDACTED\node_modules\async\dist'
Did you mean 'browser.js'?```

Comment: Still `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process/browser' in '/path/to/my/js'` after "npm i process".

Comment: I have done it and still 'process is not defined'

Comment: It worked for me, though I don't understand why this is needed. I understand that `process` is a Node thing which isn't available in the browser, but I thought Webpack would always be evaluated in Node context regardless?

Comment: @Simone yes I share your bewilderment. I somehow worked out that this incantation fixed the problem, but you would think that ’process’ would be automagically handled by Webpack

Comment: I specifically had to add `.js` at the end. So;

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ process: 'process/browser.js' })`

Comment: Was facing the issue but for me updating the packages to their latest version solved the problem

Answer (score 50):

> For namespaced environment variables (more secure) check lines 10 - 28 on this [StackBlitz page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-kdfi4z?file=index.js).

## With [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package:

1. Install `dotenv`:

   `yarn add -D dotenv` or `npm i -D dotenv`
2. Add `.env` file in your project root with the required variables:

   ```
   NODE_ENV=development
   apiKey=w23io222929kdjfk
   domain=example.domain.org
   ```
3. Define these variables with [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

   ```js
   // webpack.config.js
   const webpack = require('webpack')
   const dotenv = require('dotenv')

   // this will update the process.env with environment variables in .env file
   dotenv.config();

   module.exports = {
     //...
     plugins: [
       // ...
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
       })
       // ...
     ]
     //...
   }
   ```
4. Access environment variables in your source code:

   ```js
   // src/index.js
   alert(process.env.NODE_ENV)
   alert(process.env.apiKey)
   ```

StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-kdfi4z?file=index.js

Comment: after lot of struggle this solution works !! thanks man.

Comment: Just like coderLogs, I struggled for a while before finding this gem. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi, This is not working for env variables set at runtime by docker.

Comment: @Hem, the variables are picked up from `.env` file.  If this file is missing in your Docker working directory; it may not work.

Comment: Beware of this method. This will use .env file to override any existing env var. Better to call `dotenv.config()` first, then define the plugin: `'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)`

Comment: Hi @jackblk, I've updated the answer.  Please check now.

Comment: This bakes _all_ environment variables into your client code, potentially including things you should really not be making public and definitely making the build bigger than it needs to be. That's why existing tools _prefix_ env vars for the client - e.g. CRA uses REACT_APP_ and Next uses NEXT_PUBLIC_.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, I've added `line # 10 - 28` on the [Stack Blitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-kdfi4z) for the use case where you need only specific namespaced env-variables.

Comment: Off-site links should be _supplemental_. Most people will just copy-paste what's in the answer, so your _default_ should be secure.

Comment: Defining webpack plugin worked for me with cross-env

Comment: @jonrsharpe correct. I almost published a new version with this, good thing that i read through all the compressed & minified code. This should not be appearing as a valid answer!!

Comment: You sir, are a gosh-dang hero.

Comment: @JCollier, 

Answer (score 43):

This is how i resolved the

> ReferenceError: process is not defined

error with **Webpack 5**

1. `npm i --save-dev process`
2. Delete the "node_modules" folder
3. Add `const webpack = require('webpack');` at the top of your config file
4. In your webpack config file, plugin section, add below:

   ```
   plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       process: 'process/browser',
   }),
   ```
5. Also in the webpack add the alias like below:

   ```
   resolve: {
    alias: {
        process: "process/browser"
    },
   ```
6. Now do `npm i`

...and when you build your application the error will disappear.
you can read about webpck migration [[here]](https://medium.com/@arianpopalyar/webpack-4-to-webpack-5-migration-9bc683d2bc72)

Comment: A very  very big thank you @Arian Popalyar for posting this useful answer. I Checked a lot of answers on stackoverflow but they couldn't solve it. Finally after applying your trick it resolved the issue.

Comment: This worked for me for Cypress after upgrading to Webpack 5. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't change anything for me :-|

Answer (score 22):

**Webpack 5** removes the ability to access environment variables using the notation `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`.  I had this same problem because I was getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` error in my browser console.  From [the documentation of porting from v4 to v5 of Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/), they mention the following:

**1. Before upgrading to v5, [verify that you can easily do it](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/)**

> Try to set the following options in your webpack 4 configuration and
> check if build still works correctly.
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>    // ...
>    node: {
>        Buffer: false,
>        process: false
>    }
> };
> ```
>
> webpack 5 removes these options from the configuration schema and will always use false.
>
> You have to remove these options again when upgrading your
> configuration for webpack 5.

**2. Handling env vars because `process` was removed**

> - Regarding Runtime Errors:
>
>   - `process` is not defined.
>
>     - webpack 5 does no longer include a polyfill for this Node.js variable. Avoid using it in the frontend code.
>     - Want to support frontend and browser usage? Use the `exports` or `imports` package.json field to use different code depending on the
>       environment.
>
>       - Also use the `browser` field to support older bundlers,.
>       - Alternative: Wrap code blocks with the `typeof process` checks. Note that this will have a negative impact on the bundle size.
>     - Want to use environment variables with `process.env.VARIABLE`? You need to use the `DefinePlugin` or `EnvironmentPlugin` to define these
>       variables in the configuration.
>
>       - Consider using `VARIABLE` instead and make sure to check `typeof VARIABLE !== 'undefined'` too. `process.env` is Node.js specific
>         and should be avoided in frontend code.

Therefore, given the above information, it is possible to use environment variables using one of the two plugins below.

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env.MY_ENV_VAR": JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_ENV_VAR)
        }),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['MY_ENV_VAR']); // <--This is shorthand, does the same thing as the DefinePlugin
    ],
};
```

Then in your production code it's still feasable to refer to the environment variable in the same way, example:

```js
console.log(process.env.MY_ENV_VAR);
```

However, as they said in the documentation included above, using `process.env` is NOT the recommended way since that is Node.js specific.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Number #1 section of it helped me to replicate problems I was having with Webpack 5 on Webpack 4. That allowed me to pin-point where the problem was.

Answer (score 4):

Webpack 5, the easiest solution for me...

> npm install dotenv-webpack --save-dev

```js
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

Comment: ...be careful with this - you might accidentally leak configuration credentials(i.e: database info etc.)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid error like denoted in the question I had have provide in webpack.config.js the next configuration (note defining variable level: `process.env`):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)
            })
```

Now it works fine. I'm using webpack 5.30.0, Vue 2.6.12 and vuelidate 0.7.6.

Error I had before in browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.../node_modules/vuelidate/lib/withParams.js
```

It is not good thing, that browser client library "vuelidate" requires Node.js specific env variables. Confused build and runtime areas in library.

Comment: If you need to load .env file, call `dotenv.config()` first, then use this answer. Aakash's answer will override env var from .env file.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me to allow reading env variables inside React, using *"webpack": "^5.1.3",*

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpackConfig = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
    })
  ],
};
```

:)

Comment: When i log the process , the env object is empy. why?

Answer (score 3):

Having `dotenv-webpack`/`dotenv` in your `webpack` and still doesn't work on **Angular**? Most probably you're trying to access `process.env` when running the `Angular` app on the browser (without `Angular Universal`), e.g. by `ng serve`.

Run `npm i -S process` and then in `polyfills.ts` paste the code below

```
import * as process from "process";
window["process"] = process;
```

Alternatively, if that's not the case and you're looking for `webpack` to obtain environmental variables then (I don't know why no one suggested yet) `dotenv-webpack` is the simplest one.

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const webpackConfig = {
  plugins: [new dotenv()]
};
module.exports = webpackConfig; // Export all custom Webpack configs.
```

Of course you need to have them defined in `.env` file at the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

If it is useful for someone:

I tried almost every approach in this thread unsuccessfully.
When I went deeper into the problem I realized that what was causing this error on my application was the usage of `assert` lib:

```js
import * as assert from 'assert';
... 
assert(myVariable !== undefined, "Try to update undefined myVariable ");
```

BTW: I'm using Angular@~11.2.7

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing to check if you're sure you've properly set up dotenv or some other way to inject the environment variables, is that you are actually referencing the correct environment variable in your browser-side code! For example even if

`process.env.ENVIRONMENT`

is properly defined, you would get the above error for writing:

`process.env.EENVIRONMENT`

(note the misspelling)

This stumped me because I was expecting to get an error related to `process.env.EENVIRONMENT` being `undefined`, instead of `process`, but of course webpack is totally replacing `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` with a value, not creating a `process.env` object that can be referred to elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was `process is undefined` error on internet explorer 11 using webpack 5.

This is how I solved my problem with `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR` thanks to @ArianPopalyar.
[Ref. Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359504/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined/#answer-66731232)

In addition to her solution, I added EnvironmentPlugin in webpack.config.js:

```js
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser'
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
        PATH_MODERN: 'dist/modern/domready.min.js',
        PATH_LEGACY: 'dist/legacy/domready.min.js',
        DEBUG: false
    }),
    ...
]
```

and using it in index.js

```js
if (process.env.PATH_LEGACY) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this here's something you could try:

Replace the `process/browser` with `process` or `process/browser.js`

```js
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process'
    })
```

With webpack 5 and ES6 modules I think there's some difficulty in package resolution here, which is why we need a better path for the process.

Otherwise try including this in your webpack.config:

```js
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      'process/browser': false,
    }
  },
```

This can work to overcome the error, but not sure if it doesn't actually break the place where it's being used. In my case the first suggestion worked out.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way: prepend the variable "NODE_ENV" when you call webpack i.e. `NODE_ENV=production webpack --watch`