# Webpack: Bundle.js - Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).setTimeout is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Here's my **webpack.config.js**

```
 "use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./main.js'],
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"},
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        React: 'react',
    },
    target: "node",
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
            'global': {},
        })
    ],
};
```

And **Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import Chart from 'chartjs';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import vis from 'vis';
import babel from 'babel-core';
```

The **Bundle.js** is inserted in my Index.html. The browser then gives the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).setTimeout is not a function
    at requestAnimationFrame (bundle.js:21935)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:21941)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:21187)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:20136)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:19602)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:19553)
```

What is the cause of this error, and how could I change the webpack config to make it go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by defining global in the webpack config as a plugin, with an empty input.

`'global': {},`

Comment: You mean inside the DefinePlugin?

Comment: where would define this line in webpack.config,js? @cbll

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using `uglify()` after Babelify in Gulp.

Example:

```
.transform(babelify.configure({presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}))
.bundle() .pipe(source('app.js')) .pipe(buffer()) .pipe(uglify())
```