# Error Running BluePrintJS with Electron + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, blueprint, electron-forge

All my source code is here for reference:

https://github.com/xkenneth/electron-react-blueprint-bp

I have built a nice boiler plate built up using Electron forge TypeScript + Webpack Template

https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template

and then following

https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript

Now I am trying to get BluePrintJS loaded in for the User Interface

When I run my code I get the following error:

```
index.js:2393 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

[image: image of error]

I followed the instructions here but to no avail..

[Webpack: Bundle.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359504/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined)

Any ideas?

Here's my app.jsx

```
import { Divider } from '@blueprintjs/core';


console.log('Importing react.')

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log('Importing BluePrint')

import { Button, Intent, Spinner } from "@blueprintjs/core";

function App () {
    return (<div>
                <div>Well, just go $#@! yourself!</div>
                <div><Button></Button></div>
            </div>
            )
}

function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
}

render();
```

Here's my web pack.main.config.js (I assume that this boilerplate uses web pack.main.config.js because I con't find web pack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css', '.json'],
    alias: {
        process: "process/browser"
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line of code to the top of src/renderer.ts and it worked just fine!

window.process = { env: {} } as NodeJS.Process;