# Using environment variables in vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, environment-variables

I have seen many other questions on this topic, but none have helped me.

With vue I want to use an api, but the url will change when the app is in production so in the .env file I have defined a BASE_URL, but when I use it in a vue component, it says that procces is not defined.

I've tried with webpack.DefinePlugin in webpack.config.js or naming the environment variables as VUE_APP_BASE_URL but nothing seems to work.

```
export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  data() {
    return {
      data: undefined
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get(process.env.BASE_URL + "/api/xxxxx")
      .then(res => this.data = res.data)
  },
};
```

[image]

webpack.config.js:

```
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL),
        })
    ]
```

.env:
`BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/`

webpack version: 5.48.0

Comment: How did you use the definePlugin? What webpack version are you using? What is your .env structure?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the *window's* base-url of the site from

```
window.location.origin
```

<strike>I think enviroment variables only work in the process and are lost after compilation.</strike>

Comment: Env variables are hardcoded into a bundle on compilation. window.location.origin can be used but it's not always the same as BASE_URL

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for, but it solves my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The joys of webpack. With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64553486/3462671) as a reference, change your webpack plugin section to be

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
  ]
```

and install the `process` module

`yarn add -D process`

It looks like that should pass the entire process object through to the app for you. If that doesn't work, [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015581/3462671) that one shows another way, but it requires installing dotenv.

One other useful bit of information, if you're using Vue3, you need to prefix the variable everywhere. You'd use `VUE_APP_BASE_URL="***"` in the `.env` file, and `process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL` when you're using it anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can use your env variables in a seperate .js file for e.g an axios instance like:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000, // indicates, 10000ms ie. 10 second
  body: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})

export default httpClient
```

And then use it in your Vue file like this

```
import httpClient from '../httpClient'

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  data() {
    return {
      data: undefined
    }
  },
  async created() {
    const axiosResponse = await httpClient.get('/api/xxxx')
    this.data = axiosResponse.data.yourData
  }
};
```

EDIT: You need to start your env variable with "VUE_APP_"

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: `process is not defined.`

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the vue-cli-service to run your application, as you said, you can use `VUE_APP_BASE_URL` as environment variable name:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  data() {
    return {
      data: undefined
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + "/api/xxxxx")
      .then(res => this.data = res.data)
  },
};
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

just
process.env.BASE_URL + "/api/xxxxx"

import.meta.env.BASE_URL + "api/xxxxx"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).