# How the correct url of my server is picked when making GET request, when in console.log I see only empty string?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, frontend, create-react-app

Using create-react-app, webpack4.3, axios

I have console logged `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in both server and browser, but all I see is `""`. Then, how the correct url of my server is picked when making GET request, when in console.log I see only empty string?

I see the correct url in Network tabs of developer tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs process.env.PUBLIC\_URL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69986341/reactjs-process-env-public-url-is-not-working)

Comment: No @doneforaiur

Comment: How do you set this env variable?

Comment: Can you share a screengrab or a code example of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In create-react-app docs about [environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) they have mentioned this **two times**

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name

so the weirdest part is when log `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` and its is `""` and not `undefined`.

---

but your requests work as expected while `rocess.env.PUBLIC_URL` is an empty string so the only thing I can think of is that you had set a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) with the base URL string in your package.json file.

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```

> To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a proxy field to your package.json 
> This way, when you fetch('/api/todos') in development, the development server will recognize that it’s not a static asset, and will proxy your request to http://localhost:4000/api/todos as a fallback.

Comment: There is a `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"` entry in my package.json

Comment: there is or there is no ?

Comment: There is one! The entry is in frontend repository package.json

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma is itset to the same value of the expected env variable?

Comment: It is set to exactly `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"`.
In server.js file, there is a line `const preferredPort = toNumber(process.env.PORT) || 4000;`. Could be a relation there!

Comment: so I think that's why requests are working when you set proxy to `http://localhost:4000` then each request you make will start with `"http://localhost:4000"` so + `""` + `the end point` is working because the server is most likely listenning on port 4000. so if u don't mind please remove the proxy line from package.json **then   run npm start again** then try to send a request and tell me if it is still working. I can't be sure from your code that the server is listenning on port `4000` or  `toNumber(process.env.PORT)`

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma or easier just get rid of `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` from the request

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely