# Create config file for env variables

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a file in the src folder called config.js that contains all my variables, and I read them from .env file

```
const config = {
  ENVIRONMENT: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  API_URL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
 .....
};

export default config;
```

and the .env file

```
NODE_ENV="dev"
VUE_APP_API_URL="http://localhost:3005/"
```

and my main.js

```
...
    import config from './config';
...
const isProduction = config.ENVIRONMENT === 'production';
```

now in my main.js when I try to import the config file and trying to read it, it give me error

```
 'process' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)?

Comment: @TrietDoan no I am using vue 2, and using this command `vue serve src/main.js`

Comment: this is probably the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359504/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined