# Allowing access to process and process.env in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I'm using environment variables to set the basename of a react-router-dom BrowserRouter. However, Webpack 5 does not allow accessing environment variables.

From other stackoverflow questions, I've seen that using this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    process: 'process/browser',
})
```

makes `process` available. However, `process.env` is empty (`{}`).

Also, if I use

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env);
```

I can see the variables in my .env file are present in `process.env` in the config file but I can't find a way to make them accessible from `process.env` in the code.

I have tried:

```
new Dotenv({ systemvars: true })
```

And some other plugins suggested in [Webpack: Bundle.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359504/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined) but adding any other plugin other than the `'process/browser'` makes process not defined again.

I know there's a reason behind not allowing the use of `process.env` but I do need it.

Comment: Note that all of this is so I can universally set the basename prop for any BrowserRouter under the hood, I am using patch-package and env variables to do so, so the developer does not even notice. Maybe there is an easier way to do so. If so, let me know and I can post a more concrete question but I do think this process.env question can be useful for more people

Answer (score 0):

> [Did you check this?](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#dotenvplugin)

**DotenvPlugin**

The third-party DotenvPlugin (dotenv-webpack) allows you to expose (a subset of) dotenv variables:

```
new Dotenv({
  path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default)
  safe: true, // load .env.example (defaults to "false" which does not use dotenv-safe)
});
```