Uncaught Reference Error: process is not defined
I have a very simple Node.js and React application. I started using UserContext.Provider and received a bunch of errors about stream and crypto. I fixed those by creating fallbacks in my webpack but no I have the following error:
_stream_writable.js:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (_stream_writable.js:57:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:4:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js (index.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

I am new to coding and don't understand anything I find online to fix this very well. Could anyone walk me through step by step how to fix this?
I tried reinstalling my packages and a couple other things. I saw something about process.env and production vs development but I don't understand it well or how to fix it.
This is my App.js for my frontend:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import Home from './components/Home';
import RecipeList from './components/RecipeList';
import RecipeDetail from './components/RecipeDetail';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import FavoriteRecipes from './components/FavoriteRecipes';
import ShoppingListItems from './components/ShoppingListItems';
import Logout from './components/Logout';
import Error404 from './components/Error404';
import UserContext from './UserContext';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/verify-token', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          const { username } = jwt.decode(token);
          setCurrentUser({ username });
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Token verification failed:', err);
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const login = async (loginData) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(loginData)
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        const { username } = jwt.decode(data.token);
        setCurrentUser({ username });
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        return { success: true };
      } else {
        return { success: false, errors: data.errors };
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Login failed:', err);
      return { success: false, errors: [err.message] };
    }
  };

  const signup = async (signupData) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/signup', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(signupData)
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        const { username } = jwt.decode(data.token);
        setCurrentUser({ username });
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        return { success: true };
      } else {
        return { success: false, errors: data.errors };
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Signup failed:', err);
      return { success: false, errors: [err.message] };
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setCurrentUser(null);
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  };

  if (currentUser === null && isLoggedIn) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <Router>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser, isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn }}>
        {isLoggedIn && <Navbar />}
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/login"
            element={isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to="/" replace={true} /> : <Login login={login} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/signup"
            element={isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to="/" replace={true} /> : <SignUp signup={signup} />}
          />
          {!isLoggedIn ? (
            <Route
              path="/*"
              element={
                <div>
                  <h2>Please log in or sign up</h2>
                  <p>
                    Don't have an account? <a href="/signup">Sign up here</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              }
            />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList />} />
              <Route path="/recipes/:id" element={<RecipeDetail />} />
              <Route path="/favorite-recipes" element={<FavoriteRecipes />} />
              <Route path="/shopping-list-items" element={<ShoppingListItems />} />
              <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout logout={logout} />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
            </>
          )}
        </Routes>
        {isLoggedIn && <Footer />}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;```


Hello! It would help if you could provide the code that you're trying to run, so that we can try and find a solution

You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359504/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined

This is specific to your project setup and app, which are unknown. The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to be precisely addressed. "process" is node var, it needs to be polyfilled in a browser when used but commonly that it's accessed is the actual problem. This can occur if you use node-only packages in a browser

"The jsonwebtoken library is only made for the Node.js runtime.". You cannot use it in your React component

Does this answer your question? cant use jsonwebtoken with latest version of react
